# what does []() mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i cant find anything on it, and the reasoning behind asking is because Deno uses "async iterables" which is totally new to me, looking at the mozilla javascript mdn its defined as `[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {}` in a object; which then creates the question, what does `[something]() {}` do in detail, and how does it work?

Comment: Those iterables seem to be, well, [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). Here's a [friendlier tutorial](https://javascript.info/iterable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The square brackets are a computed property name. Using them, you can define a dynamic property on an object literal or class, like this:

```js
const propName = 'fooprop';
const obj = {
  [propName]: 'value'
};
console.log(obj);
```

The `() {}` after it is using shorthand method syntax to define a function on an object literal or class, like this:

```js
const obj = {
  fn() {
    console.log('fn running');
  }
};
obj.fn();
```

It's very nearly equivalent to:

```js
const obj = {
  fn: function() {
    console.log('fn running');
  }
};
obj.fn();
```

(not *entirely* equivalent though - unlike `function`s, methods can't be constructed by being called with `new` - which is not really a limitation)

So `[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {}` just puts those two together: it defines a property whose key is `Symbol.asyncIterator` on the object, whose value is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ES6 computed property names:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Answer (score 0):

It's running a function or method based on a dynamically-resolved name.

Consider this example:

```js
const o = {
    foo() {}
};

const methodName = 'foo';

o[methodName](); // runs o.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the square brackets when u want to dynamically compute an object literal's property name. For example

```
function foo() {
    // some logic

    return 'foo';

}

 // some variable in your code
 const bar = 'bar'

 // using square brackets to dynamically compute property names for the object
 const obj = {
   [foo()]: 'hello',
   [bar]: 'there'
 }

 // console.log(obj.foo) will show 'hello'
 // console.log(obj.bar) will show 'there'
```

This is very useful when you want an object's property name to be dynamic. However
the `[Symbol.asyncIterator]()` property is somewhat special. For an object to be an async iterable(which means you can use `for await ...of` to iterate over the object) it has to follow certain protocols in javascript. The property `[Symbol.asyncIterator]` as a function defines the default async iterator for an object. You can read more about it here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator